# Visual Studio SSAS Tabular Model does not show existing connections

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas, tabular

I'd like to write a SQL Query to extract data from a SQL Table into the SSAS Table. I do not have this option available, as normally I should go over 'Model' > 'Existing Connections'. In my case, there is no option 'Existing Connections'. Anything I could be doing wrongly?

Comment: You are giving a problem, and asking if there's anything you are doing wrong, but you never say what you've done and tried so far.

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe you need to *create* a connection?

Comment: Hi Brian. I went to Solution Explorer > Add Data Source > I added a SQL Server Database > It won't show up in 'Existing Connections'

Comment: Hi Hans, I created a connecion in various ways but still it does not appeare in 'existing connections' and thus it does not allow me to write a sql statement to pull specific data from the database into a table

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue: The option doesn't show in the Model menu. Instead, I opened the **Tabular Model Explorer** window (View -> Other Windows). There you find a folder **Data Sources** containing the existing data sources. Select the data source and in the context menu you will find the **Import New Tables** option.

Answer (score 1):

I use VS2017 : In the "Tabular Model Explorer" right click on the 'Data Source' and you can see the option "Import New Tables".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor to open the .bim file in the project.  Scroll down the end of the file.  You should see something like:

```
"annotations": [
  {
    "name": "ClientCompatibilityLevel",
    "value": "400"
  }
```

If the Value is 500 change it to 400.  Save and reopen the solution.  The "Existing Connections" should reappear in the Model dropdown.
Had the same issue.  I'd made a prior backup before it disappeared, which when I opened the backup solution it was there.  So I compared the files, made the change and it reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I had the same problem today.
It happens each time I open my project in VS 2017.

My solution is to open my Data sources and enter my credentials again. I guess that VS2017 does not have access to the data when you open the project (it probably does not save the password) and therefore it cannot retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

As "Klaus K" mention: "Existing Connections" reappear, but **ClientCompatibilityLevel = 400** removes **Calculation Groups**, so not very useful for me..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31582665)